# Emberjs: deleteRecord() doesn't update model consistently

Tags: ember.js

(To Repro:  Click into a list, add a task, try to remove that task.)

I have an app where I can create multiple lists of tasks, each task can be commented on.

I am having trouble getting consistent behavior when deleting a record.  I can delete a record within an already existing model.  However once I create a Record, I can't seem to delete it.  But then once I leave a page (transition to another Route) and come back, I can delete again.  Is this a problem with .save()?

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/oDOsoqA/3/edit

Comment: Your jsbin seems to work fine.

Comment: try adding a task, and then deleting it.

Comment: what version of ember data is this using?

Comment: it's using the latest, and add a task, not a comment (it's at the bottom)

Comment: Yes Yes. I saw. Its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the {async : true} on the hasMany tasks.  Honestly this functionality is a little shaky (My guess is that it should be nailed down and functionality will be a bit more apparent once they've hit a solid 1.0).

You can get rid of the push and change the links to the model and it all works, but I'm not sure about your async necessities.

http://jsbin.com/oDOsoqA/4/edit

```
addTask : function(){
  var foo = this.store.createRecord('task', { 
    description : '',
    list : this.get('model'),
    comments : []  
  });
  //this.get('tasks').pushObject(foo);
  foo.save();
}
```

Comment: yeah that's it.  thanks so much.  Really too bad about the async:true bit...I would hope that gets fixed soon.  Now if I refresh, my records don't load.